# How to make Site A as referral?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have three sites...The source of the link is Site A, to Site B, the the goal is set to a page in Site C where there is a link in Site B. I want to goal flow to have Site A as referral/source rather than Site B. Please Help.

Site a is a third party site, so i have no control over it. site b and site c are under different domain. I want something like this.. Site A -> Site B -> Site C, Site A should be the referrer where Site C holds my goal page.

Comment: Are all the sites running on different top-level domains?

Comment: yes they are from different domains.. like this site a- sitea.com, site b- siteb.com and site c - sitec.com (for example)